# how can i redirect dynamic URL in worpress base on ID in htaccess or wp-config or function.php

Tags: php, redirect, urls

I want to redirect 301

worpress.com/NewsInfoPrint?id=13624

to the below URL

wordpress.com/news/13624/

// number is post  ID in WordPress and I need for all posts to do that, so the number is dynamic

how can I do that?

Comment: does `/news/13624/` currently work if you go there directly? Could you use the permalinks setting page to set it to use that URL format?

Comment: Yes work this url I want to redirect. Do u have a solution for this